# Group add request using facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there any built-in "Group add request" actions that come with the facebook graph API? Like the built-in [Like action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/likes/)? That happens with a users request. I would like to do this from an external website, just like the Like action works

For example the user is active in a forum, where different categories have their own facebook group page, and they would like to access the group without having to actually log on facebook and make the request.

Comment: Now @Tommy Crush's reply is outdated. The api was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used. P/S: Sorry I can't comment because of repulation [DOC](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/group/members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/):

> Invite User
>
> Applications can invite users to a group by issuing a POST request to /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID with an app access_token.
>
> Note that user being invited must be a user of the application. The user will be sent a notification saying that they have been invited to the group. The notification will take them to the group page. Users can only be invited once. Subsequent invites will fail.

So you the user will have to authorize your app, and then you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. The user will authorize the app since it would be interested in getting access to groups easier

Comment: Please accept answers that solve the problem, so that others can find solutions more easily.

Comment: I will accept when I am allowed to, thank you. I need to let 15 minutes until I can accept an answer

Comment: would you share your code to do "invite user to facebook group". I'm facing this problem now. Please help